# Storing password hash - varchar vs varbinary

Tags: sql, passwords

Is there a real difference (meaning does it have any added [security] value to do it this or that way) in storing password hash as varchar or a varbinary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really.

Storing it as a `varbinary` will allow you to use characters outside of your current codepage.  You could avoid that by using `nvarchar` over `varchar`.

Storing it as `varbinary` will also make the data present in a hexidecimal format, but this is really not any serious level of protection.

A good reason to store it in `varbinary` would be that it is in fact binary data, not character data - but this has nothing to do with securing the data per se.

Your security will come form using a proper hashing algorithm and properly securing access to the database/table(s) in question, including ensuring that applications with the proper access levels parameterize their queries.

Comment: I think I know quite enough about password security, but I always used nvarchar to store the hashes and I've done some research recently and it seems that a lot of posts use varbinary, so I've been wondering whether I missed something or not.